# How do i get AnimatedSwitcher to do a smooth transition?

Tags: flutter

The fade results in the images blinking. I want one image to fade in fully before the other fades out - so that at all times is at least one image with full opacity. Right now it looks as though the switchInCurve and switchOutCurve are not synchronized.
I have setup the animated switcher as follows:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
      switchInCurve: Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve:Curves.linear ) ,
      switchOutCurve: Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve:Curves.linear ) ,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
      child: sleepingBearImage,
),
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you share some videos or elaborate on the question more.

Comment: Why don't you use [AnimatedCrossFade](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html) instead?

Comment: AnimatedCrossFade shows the same behaviour where the first image blinks out before the second is fully opaque.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Images and AnimatedSwitcher, the solution is to preload all images you going to use for first time, remember to do that on Widget loading: **didChangeDependencies()**.

example:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/images/on-00.png"), context);
    precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/images/on-01.png"), context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```